# Scraping location from website that has no clear way to organizing url

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, postman, gis

So I have been scraping location data of different retailers across Canada for some research.The work I am doing is to help give some idea on how some industries are and were effect by covid.So far most store locator pages have been pretty straight forward with a single link where I can play with variable such as lng and lat in python. However I have come across a website that I am having trouble figuring out how they request data for locations. This retailer being LCBO. The store locator has a small option at the bottom of all pages and when a location is inputted it is just a overlay on the orginal page. Here is the link to LCBO: https://www.lcbo.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/lcbo

If anyone has any suggestions to how I could manipulate the link that is used for their location in the chrome network tab that be great. This seems to be the most difficult store retailer I have found after doing a few large retailers. So any suggestion would be great.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED OR ATTEMPTED:
So I have used postman and sent the curl file of this link: https://www.lcbo.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/AjaxStoreLocatorResultsView?catalogId=10051&langId=-1&storeId=10203&orderId=
In postman I have tried playing with the langid and storeid. However, my edited request have not worked or even when I edit( change numbers) the params I get nothing new. Maybe I am not inputting number that make logical sense but when I add 1 to everything nothing new happens. Maybe the curl link I have is a bad one and I am missing url that is better way to request the locations?

Side note, hoping to write a large post here on how store locations are **scraped** as I am GIS student and found that there is a lot of other forms of **scraping** shown in examples but very location based. However, one problem at a time.

Thanks!

THE CODE BELOW IS HOW I HAVE APPROACHED THIS BEFORE!

```
import requests
import json
import numpy as np
import csv 

x = range(0,100)
row = []
for pages in x:
    url = f"https://www.couche-tard.com/stores_new.php?lat=46.8257&lng=-71.2349&services=&region=quebec&page={pages}"
    payload={}
    headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://www.couche-tard.com/trouvez-votre-magasin?address=Qu%C3%A9bec,Quebec,Canada&lat=46.8257&lng=-71.2349',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'dnt': '1'
  }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    stores = json.loads(response.text)

    tmp_row = []
    for store in stores['stores'].values():
        Match_address = store["address"]
        Match_city = store["city"]
        display_brand = store["display_brand"]

        tmp_row.append([Match_address, Match_city, display_brand])
    row.extend(tmp_row) 
    
with open('couche.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as CSVFile:
    writer = csv.writer(CSVFile, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow([
        "address",
        "city",
        "display_brand",
        ])
    writer.writerows(row)
```

Comment: You're more likely to get useful feedback here by providing your unsuccessful attempts so people can see what you've tried and either point out why it hasn't worked or what you may have missed.

Comment: If you look at the network tab, you see the locator form makes an Ajax call to the following endpoint: https://www.lcbo.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/AjaxStoreLocatorResultsView?catalogId=10051&langId=-1&storeId=10203&orderId= maybe try that out in Postman to see if you can get any results back.

Comment: @kungphu Ok yea thats on me, Il add a flow of what I attempted and how it turned out. Plus any code format I tried.

Comment: @bo-oz I tried postman but got no results back and when editing anything I would either get nothing or get back the same thing. Il update the original post.

Comment: There's a parameter called `citypostalcode` you could manipulate to mimick someone using the search in the store locator. You probably should also copy all headers and other query/body parameters, until you get back the HTML the API seems to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a response in Postman, by following these steps:

1. use store locator on website, with network tab open
2. you see an ajax call to some location
3. right click on the request and choose copy --> copy as curl
4. open postman and click import
5. select raw and past the curl code
6. run the request in postman
7. success

more info on copy/pasting the request here: https://dev.to/stuartcreed/how-to-copy-a-http-request-to-from-the-network-taboo-postman-5835

Curl for a random request:

```
curl 'https://www.lcbo.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/AjaxStoreLocatorResultsView?catalogId=10051&langId=-1&storeId=10203&orderId=' \
  -H 'authority: www.lcbo.com' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Mobile Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'origin: https://www.lcbo.com' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'referer: https://www.lcbo.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/lcbo' \
  -H 'accept-language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es;q=0.6,de;q=0.5,zh-TW;q=0.4,zh;q=0.3,fr;q=0.2' \
  -H 'cookie: JSESSIONID=0000vBbIDBjsUM58mEmmzaCYUqn:ecomapp02; bv_sha=2019082000; BVBRANDID=50d350fa-9bf3-450a-8c14-c3d17414d578; BVBRANDSID=5034fc5b-874c-4b47-b20f-5fbb0efc4d8b; s_fid=5A14CCAB963E6B8B-26111870A9508B76; gpv_pagename=homepage; s_cc=true; kampyle_userid=4c09-32a1-9cad-0c04-c9a7-725a-8f95-67b0; __z_a=748269966287106654528710; languagepopupshown=true; lang=en; WC_latitude=52.3501568; WC_longitude=4.908646399999999; WC_SESSION_ESTABLISHED=true; WC_PERSISTENT=XgKKFMQkD5auLS4bGLnHygfywCvZNo4pPATxjd9d1dc%3D%3B2021-07-15+02%3A00%3A28.398_1626328799364-193523_10203_-1002%2C-1%2CCAD%2CYKP40yGPqEEbpHLRIgbiN7BNgljfv5jFfuiUZ5cHWuJ0yqBdGfRFN3lxsaSNTA106UezjIyXERst27mEguaTKA%3D%3D_10203; WC_AUTHENTICATION_-1002=-1002%2CetYHJunN2fPHnqWYb6iXk2V4thGGKMCP7yRvypmsoac%3D; WC_ACTIVEPOINTER=-1%2C10203; WC_stCity=toronto; WC_USERACTIVITY_-1002=-1002%2C10203%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C677837368%2CwuVMSWYcMPzSz0F5IG1h%2BK7SE3Ia5bb%2FmnWOhA1lwPFp78OQHUHJt3TMpAt%2BwkUbTggLMzFB75302vvSErzuY9QSsvEEUY%2FpKGkgAoIvKsy1KOxeh2J1Pxvx%2FURbA8RXNwI4KUUPl%2FyqCRJ6tkc0K%2F7mQ9I%2FT77nJ2cgeI9SYTKqp2xIopLduH5RLIkhCkSBxLLBGagA6EzayVj7%2FFkfDEYTl7Q84F4iiuTzLpld5HxiMDm32qKiizMSJdJDmcE1; WC_GENERIC_ACTIVITYDATA=[5248871728%3Atrue%3Afalse%3A0%3ABUQiX0jAISFBFLIbw5p%2FJHNVr%2FS4bfEq%2BkV%2FUnDS1NY%3D][com.ibm.commerce.context.ExternalCartContext|null][com.ibm.commerce.context.entitlement.EntitlementContext|10502%2610502%26null%26-2000%26null%26null%26null][com.ibm.commerce.store.facade.server.context.StoreGeoCodeContext|null%26null%26null%26null%26null%26null][com.ibm.commerce.catalog.businesscontext.CatalogContext|10051%26null%26false%26false%26false][CTXSETNAME|Store][com.ibm.commerce.context.base.BaseContext|10203%26-1002%26-1002%26-1][com.ibm.commerce.context.audit.AuditContext|1626328799364-193523][com.lcbo.lco.commerce.context.LCOContext|false][com.ibm.commerce.context.experiment.ExperimentContext|null][com.ibm.commerce.giftcenter.context.GiftCenterContext|null%26null%26null][com.ibm.commerce.context.globalization.GlobalizationContext|-1%26CAD%26-1%26CAD]; __zjc2339=5109266816; QueueITAccepted-SDFrts345E-V3_2020pandemic=EventId%3D2020pandemic%26QueueId%3D00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%26RedirectType%3Ddisabled%26IssueTime%3D1626330141%26Hash%3D7657f416295433996cce6c372ea650f6be4cecb9b71bee059038766af32fa1b7; WC_CartOrderId_10203=; kampyleUserSession=1626330141718; kampyleUserSessionsCount=2; kampyleSessionPageCounter=1; kampyleUserPercentile=25.946945797403643; cd_user_id=17aa8d494936a8-0c00c250f0a3b5-34657601-232800-17aa8d49494866; pageLoadAverage=5%3A32; s_getNewRepeat=1626330158348-New; s_sq=lcboprod%3D%2526pid%253Dhomepage%2526pidt%253D1%2526oid%253D%25250A%252509%252509%252509%252509%252509%25250A%252509%252509%252509%252509%2526oidt%253D3%2526ot%253DSUBMIT' \
  --data-raw 'fromPage=CategoryPage&features=&citypostalcode=toronto&latitude=&longitude=&productId=&ageChecked=%5Bobject+SubmitEvent%5D&isFavoriteStore=false&requesttype=ajax' \
  --compressed
```

Comment: I did all this with postman, however the problem I am having is what params would I change to make the search radius bigger or loop lata and long numbers?  For example in the url I have previously just looped late a long or changed radius range. Here When I insert new data I find no change or nothing returns.

Comment: I included an example how I attempted this before just to show my point of view